# Does MailChimp host images for HTML emails?

Tags: html, mailchimp

If I want to send out HTML emails via MailChimp, would they host images for me or do I have to do it on my own server?

Comment: I'm also interested in having a "if you're having trouble viewing this email click here to view it online" link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MailChimp Full Feature List](http://www.mailchimp.com/features/full_list) :

> Free Image and File Hosting
>   Upload images and files into your campaign without having to worry about extra charges.

Answer (score 3):

You can upload images in designer view. Than keep URL and use it in advanced view with your HTML. It's not as easy and sleek, but it works.

Check details [here](http://mailchimp.com/features/image-and-file-hosting/).

You can also use Flickr to load images. And edit them with Picnic. Cool features.

Answer (score -1):

The "big famous competitor" that is an alternative to mail chimp is Constant Contact. They also offer the "click here to view this as a web page" option, I recall.